# Failed to export archive to ipa (No applicable devices found)

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

Well, just tried to create an IPA build / package with no luck. I found similar issues on the web but they didn't fix the error.

Here's the stack that it sends me while trying:

`[ERROR] :  Failed to export archive to ipa
[ERROR] :  2017-03-25 16:47:25.761 xcodebuild[29128:87514] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/fr/nqly_t5n1f13l_k9hbm9vzb80000gn/T/App_2017-03-25_16-47-25.759.xcdistributionlogs'.
[ERROR] :  1.2.840.113635.100.1.61
[ERROR] :  2017-03-25 16:47:26.196 xcodebuild[29128:87514] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionThinningStep: 0x7f8e3cd349e0>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}
[ERROR] :  error: exportArchive: No applicable devices found.
[ERROR] :

[ERROR] :  Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}`

My environment is as follows:

- OS: macOS Sierra
- Xcode: 8.21
- Appcelerator Studio: 4.8.1

Thing already tried:

- Tried to remove `rbenv` and use system ruby with no luck.
- I updated `CFPropertyList` gem as well.

Comment: In order to export an archive, you may need to have an actual iPhone plugged into your computer via USB that is certified for your developer account. I'm not 100% sure why, but I'm pretty sure that is a dumb requirement.

Comment: @David, tried it and didn't work. I double checked that the phone I had connected was on my device list, but same issue.

Comment: Looks like an issue with Appcelerator itself. I opened the .xcodeproj and archived it through Xcode with no issues.

Comment: Glad it was resolved. I had an issue like that where the problem was 100% because my phone wasn't plugged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the release of SDK 6.0.3.GA they solved also a problem with ad-hoc release, have a look at this one:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24483

In these last weeks I'm having problems with in-house distribution but for me ad-hoc works.

Comment: Issue was actually related to 6.0.2.GA as you said. Tried with 6.0.3.GA and works now.